# What does the phrase "heading for a poleaxing" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I was checking whether *biannual* meant twice a year or once every two years (short answer: both) when I stumbled upon [this example](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biannual) containing the phrase *"heading for a poleaxing"*:

[image: Poleaxing]

I've never seen *poleaxe* used outside of a combat or historical context. Is this a common phrase in some parts of the world? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: In at least some instances, it might mean "heading for a beheading."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't go so far as to say *common*, at least in American English, but the phrase does exist.  As you alluded to, the verb use comes from the weapon:

> to attack, strike, or fell with or as if with a poleax ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poleax))

The idiomatic use may be more common in British English, judging by it having a special entry in the [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pole-axed):

> If someone is pole-axed, they are so surprised or shocked that they do not know what to say or do. [mainly British, informal]

As [Ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poleaxing%2Cpoleaxed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoleaxing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoleaxed%3B%2Cc0), the adjective **poleaxed** is significantly more common than the infinitive usage.

Answer (score 0):

A poleaxe is a weapon, resembling a stout stave with an axe head and spike incorporated; in common use during the 15th. century. It was also used to slaughter large animals. The term "poleaxing" was adapted and carried forward in modern parlance, as a description of someone's sudden incapacitation "he dropped, as though poleaxed".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your example "poleaxing" is a typical journalistic pun that works because it is about a politician hoping to be elected at the polls.

Pole - homonym - poll as in elections

to axe = to be cut down with an axe.

A poleaxe is an ancient military weapon*. It also appears in the phrase "He went down like a poleaxed ox" = He collapsed like an ox collapses when hit with a poleaxe.

"heading for a poleaxing" will be slaughtered/defeated heavily at the polls.

*OED

> **Poleaxe:** (n.)
>
> 1. (a) Originally: a weapon for use in close combat, existing in various forms but generally having a head consisting of an axe blade or hammer-head, balanced at the rear by a pointed fluke. Later also: any of various long-handled weapons of this type, as carried (now only ceremonially) by the bodyguard of a monarch or great personage.)

**Verb**

> **1. transitive. To fell, kill, or stun (an animal) with a blow from a poleaxe.**

The etymology of **poleaxe** is obscure but a fair bet is that the "Pole" part of it refers to the Old English "pol" meaning "head" - i.e. "designed to split open a head."